# How to apply polymorphism to xml deserialization?

Tags: java

I have two types of xml:

```
<exec><cmd>STATISTIC</cmd><param></param></exec>

<exec><cmd>FILE_TO_CLIENT</cmd><param><filePath>"/opt/tst"</filePath><msg>"ls- la"</msg></param></exec>
```

I need to pass them to function that  might return two types of class object

```
class Statistic    {
}

class FileToClient
{
  String msg;
  String filePath;
}
```

In case the message is of type `statistic` - no fields are required. In case it is `file_to_client` , `msg` and `filePath` fields should be filled from xml.

How should I organize my class hierarchy so that the deserializer function could return both type of objects?

Answer (score 2):

First of all.... Classes in java **ALWAYS** starts with **`UPPERCASE`**.
Second your question is not clear, but I will try to explain basic inheritance.

---

If you want both classes being same type to be returned by same method you need to have a common `Parent` class. All classes in Java inherits from Object class, but better if you define your own parent like this:

```
// parent class common to others
class YourParent {
    // put here any common attributes for child classes
}
```

Then make your child classes extend from parent:

```
class Statistic extends YourParent 
{
}

class FileToClient extends YourParent 
{
String msg;
String filePath;

}
```

Finally, you can use both `FileToClient` and `Statistics` as `YourParent` classes.

For example, as return type in a method:

```
public YourParent doSomething() {
    if (something)
        FileToClient f = //
        return f;  // valid
    } else {
        Statistic s = //
        return s;  // valid also!!!
    }
}
```